# VBA SUM Unique Values to different column

Tags: vba, excel

Would someone be willing to point me into the right direction please. I want to sum up duplicate values and put them into a different column.

[image]

In column P, I have the list from column K with all duplicates removed.

In column N, is the Total.

For example in column K, there is a duplicated value '9175-2278' and if you SUM up the total of those 2 values you get a total of '604'.

I want that value to be inserted in column Q.

Could someone please point me in the right direction please.

I have tried codes like the following but with no luck

Sub sample()

```
Dim lastRow As Integer, num As Integer, i As Integer
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lastRow
    num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("K1:K" & lastRow), 0)

    If i = num Then
        Cells(i, 3) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("K1:K" & lastRow), Cells(i, 1), Range("Q1:Q" & lastRow))

    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: `=SUMIF(K:K,P3, M:M)` put that in `Q3` and drag it down

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much :) really big help thank you. Is there any way to convert that into a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Formula

`=SUMIF(K:K,P3, N:N)` put that in `Q3` and drag it down

or as a macro

```
Sub Main()
    With Range("Q3")
        .Formula = "=SUMIF(K:K, P3, N:N)"
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q3:Q" & Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```